# How to show particular product on particular page in wordpress woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have tried lot solution but my product layout not looking good. please check this link on which i want to show particular product on this page. http://inncrotech.com/design/my-design/

Comment: can you post php code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this style

```
        .entry-content .woocommerce .products ul, .entry-content .woocommerce ul.products {
            display: inline-flex;
             margin-top: 40px;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks Its Working but i want show like my shop page.

Comment: when i apply this property this will affect on shop page also.